# script to attach photos to a survey response

Tags: javascript

Is there a script that will allow a survey taker to attach 2 photos to a survey response? I'm creating a web page for my 25th high school reunion. I would like to post an online survey that will also allow the survey taker to upload or attach a "then" photo and "now" photo with their responses. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ok, it works. thank you!!! now i need to know how to make it send the form with attchments (pics) to my email. i'm so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ready to go, just add server side script to handle the images. [example](http://jsfiddle.net/yGVmK/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm a little confused tho. Do I paste the html, the javascript, or both? And how do I make sure it attaches to the email with the form responses? Sorry, I'm not very experienced at this yet.

Comment: Is supose that it will be easyer to add your existing form to the one in the example. And don`t forget to add the JavaScript.

Comment: ok, it works. thank you!!! now i need to know how to make it send the form with attchments (pics) to my email. i'm so confused.

Comment: i would except that i don't know how to get it to send the form with attachments (pics) to my email. help please?

Comment: btw, the code i already have to browse and choose the file is: btw, the javascript i already have is: <form id="imgForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <p><label for="img0"><input type="file" id="img0" name="img0"/></label></p> </form>